# ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable error while trying to click a button through Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a page with source code like the code below.  In it after I take an action an “Undo” and a “Close” button appear.  I’m trying to click the  “Close” button.  I’ve tried all three of the chunks of code below, none are working.  Can someone please point out what I’m doing wrong, or suggest something else to try?

html source:

```
<div class="_3Aslx7L3GVI4XM7PUyYKza action-bar"><div class="container"><i class="success-icon fontello-ok-circle"></i><div class="success-message">Your stuff is going to <span>place</span> is on its way.</div><div class="gh69ID1m3_xtdTUQuwadU"><button class="c-button c-button--gray"> Undo</button></div><div class="gh69ID1m3_xtdTUQuwadU"><button class="c-button c-button--blue"> Close</button></div></div></div>
```

code attempts:

```
#driver.find_element_by_id("gh69ID1m3_xtdTUQuwadU").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.c-button.c-button--blue').click()
#driver.find_element_by_link_text('Close').click()
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementNotVisibleException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-6d570be770d7> in <module>()
      1 #driver.find_element_by_id("gh69ID1m3_xtdTUQuwadU").click()
----> 2 driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.c-button.c-button--blue').click()
      3 #driver.find_element_by_link_text('Close').click()

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in click(self)
     78     def click(self):
     79         """Clicks the element."""
---> 80         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     81 
     82     def submit(self):

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    626             params = {}
    627         params['id'] = self._id
--> 628         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    629 
    630     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    318         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    319         if response:
--> 320             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    321             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    322                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.109)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

Comment: probably your webbrowser size is misconfigured due to which the element is not visible and hence not clickable, you can see your exception type: `ElementNotVisibleException `

Comment: there's a way to take screenshot in selenium, try taking a screenshot and saving to some file just before your `driver.find_element_by` code and see what it looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element with text as **Close** is a dynamic element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.action-bar button.c-button.c-button--blue"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'action-bar')]//button[@class='c-button c-button--blue' and normalize-space()='Close']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you this code did the trick: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.action-bar button.c-button.c-button--blue"))).click()

Answer (score 0):

Try using XPATHs and Action class for this kind of scenarios.

```
BTN_xpath = //*[contains(@class, 'c-button--blue')]
WebElement btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(BTN_xpath);
Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
ac.click(btn).build().perform();
```

Also, if you are using the Firefox browser, there could be issues where its not able to interact with elements that were not visible before in the page. So, try checking a with a different browser as well.