# How to clear the default data from a textbox using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, angular, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

How to clear the default data from a textbox using Python Selenium? I am getting element not interactable error.

HTML:

```
<div class="emailAttachmentInputMobile">
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="100" ng-model="emailAttachmentRecipient" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-touched">
</div>
```

This is my python code:

```
DeleteText  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@ng-model='emailAttachmentRecipient'][@type='text']").clear()
```

Whenever I run this I am getting "Element not interactable" error.

Could someone please help me resolve this issue. I have lost so much of my time to fix this issue but still am not able to fix.

Comment: This is my html code.
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="100" ng-model="emailAttachmentRecipient" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-touched">

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share ALL your code, including the url of that page

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a couple of things as follows:

- *`clear()`* doesn't returns anything. So `DeleteText` will be always *`NULL`*.
- The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, to ***clear*** the existing text you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.emailAttachmentInputMobile input.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-valid-maxlength.ng-not-empty.ng-touched[ng-model='emailAttachmentRecipient']"))).clear()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='emailAttachmentInputMobile']//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-touched' and @ng-model='emailAttachmentRecipient']"))).clear()
    ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I have tried using both locator strategies but am getting the error


"Ordinal0 [0x00E59943+2595139]...
 Ordinal0 [0x00E011FC+2232828]
 BaseThreadInitThunk [0x769DFA29+25]
 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x770C7A9E+286]
 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x770C7A6E+238]"

Comment: Sounds like a different error all together and [Element not interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54759731/7429447) error seems to have got resolved. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: This is the error
 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: